# How to display custom fields in rally?

Tags: rally

I have a ruby script that is trying to pull up some custom fields from Rally, the filter works just fine ( the filter contains one of the custom fields i want to pull up) but when I try to display it, it doesn't show up in the list (the value returned for all custom fields is blank, while appropriate values are returned for FormattedID, Name, Description).

Here's the link [link]http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6124958/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477211/how-to-access-a-custom-field-using-rally-ruby-api).

1. Do you fetch the fields?
2. What version of WS API are you using? If it is v2.0 is `c_` prepended to the name of the field in the code?
3. How is the field spelled in your code and how that spelling compares to Name and Display Name of the field in UI?

Comment: The problem was with the versioning, as rightly mentioned in the post you linked to, for using "c_" prefixed fields, the version needs to be mentioned as a config variable. In my case,

    config[:version] => "v2.0" 

worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

There is another reason why custom fields might not appear (other than the versioning and 'c_' issues nickm mentioned). I just found this out after a ton of head banging. The Rally SDK's ui stuff will filter out all fields that are hidden (such as _ref, or other 'hidden' custom fields) so you cannot view them in your apps in grids, charts, etc. For example, when constructing a `Rally.ui.grid.Grid`, a class called `Rally.ui.grid.ColumnBuilder` is constructed and it executes a command on the columns of the chart that look like this:

```
    _removeHiddenColumns: function (columns) {
        return _.filter(columns, function (column) {
            return !column.modelField || !column.modelField.hidden;
        });
    },
```

As you can see, if you try to display any fields that are hidden (like _ref for example) in a grid, the column gets removed. So, although you may be fetching the custom fields, they will not show up unless those fields are not 'hidden'.