# In Rally SDK, show hidden fields in UI components

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

when a field is 'hidden' in Rally, they will not be shown in any of the SDK's UI components. for example, I cannot make a `rallygrid` with a column with dataIndex of `_ref` because `_ref` is a hidden field. I also have custom fields that are hidden, but I really need to use them to make columns in the `rallygrid`.

I have looked through the sdk source and know that these are removed from the SDK's ui components, so I guess I'm looking for a workaround, or a hack to get around this issue.

I commented on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24835197/2334847)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to include _ref in a grid based on a [custom store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.custom.Store). I modified a custom data grid [example](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/example/custom-data-grid) to populate a Reference column with _ref values of each record:

[image]

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    items:{ html:'<a href="https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/">App SDK 2.0rc3 Docs</a>'},
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
            model: 'userstory',
            autoLoad: true,
            listeners:{
                load: this._onDataLoaded,
                scope: this
            },
            fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', '_ref']
        })
    },
    _onDataLoaded: function(store,data){
        var records = _.map(data, function(record){
            return Ext.apply({
                Ref: record.get('_ref')
            }, record.getData());
        });
        this.add({
            xtype: 'rallygrid',
            showPagingToolbar: false,
            showRowActionsColumn: false,
            editable: false,
            store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                data: records
            }),
            columnCfgs:[
                {
                    xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    text: 'ID',
                    dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
                    width: 100,
                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                },
                {
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'Name'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Reference',
                    dataIndex: 'Ref',
                    flex: 1
                }
            ]
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: This method did allow me to display the custom field columns, thanks